# Trying to run an exe file created from a cpp file in java

Tags: java, pipe, deadlock, processbuilder

I'm trying to run an executable file created from a cpp program in java. If I double-click the exe file, it works just fine, but if I run the file using ProcessBuilder, it gets stuck for some reason, it prints most of the expected output and doesn't continue, also making the entire Java program not responding.
here's my code:

```
    String filePath = FirstScreenController.getFile().getPath();
    ProcessBuilder launcher = new ProcessBuilder("ClusteringProgram\\Release\\main.exe",filePath);
    launcher.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        /*File file = FirstScreenController.getFile();
        Path newPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ClusteringProgram").resolve("K12.fasta");//Moving the file to the 
        Files.copy(Paths.get(file.getPath()), newPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);*/
        System.out.println("Execution started");
        p = launcher.start();
        InputStream stderr = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

        }
        p.waitFor();//Waiting for the process to finish running
        System.out.println("Execution completed");  
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException  e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get stuck"? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also recommend [this StackOverflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The program doesn't end, It doesn't print the entire output.
Again, if I double-click the executable file outside of Java, it works fine.
@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat: There's enough information here. It just doesn't look like it. MVCEing this would be impossible for anyone who needs to ask the question.

Comment: This is a valid question, it is not off-topic and it has been answered below.

Comment: @Joshua: Why would MCVEing this be impossible? At the very least, showing us the C++ side and removing the dependence on `filePath` would be a good start, and that doesn't require already knowing what's wrong.

Comment: @user2357112: I'm not going to say obviously because it isn't obvious. The problem depends somehow on specific I/O buffer sizes and specific outputs from the second program. But there are no I/O buffer sizes in this fragment and almost certainly none in the C++ code either.

Answer (score -2):

Close your stream. That's what's causing you to hang. I write code like this quite a bit.

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    br.close(); // You need this or p can hang
    p.waitFor();
```

<strike>In addition, you called `launcher.redirectStandardError(true);` so you actually need all this to gather both stdout and stderr together:</strike> The whole rest of this answer is wrong. I don't know what is causing the deadlock. I'm leaving the large code fragment here in case it's some strange library bug and it turns out that the dual-thread reading technique is required to work around it.

```
    final object lock = new object();
    InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    final InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
    one = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
               InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
               BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
               while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                   synchronized(lock) {
                      System.out.println(line2);
                   }
               }
               br2.close(); // you need this or p can hang
        }  
    };
    one.start();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    br.close(); // You need this or p can hang
    for (;;) {
        try {
            one.join();
            break;
        } catch (InterruptedException v) {
            /* if there's something that might want the main thread's attention handle it here */
        }
    }
    p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Why are you reading from `getErrorStream`? `launcher.redirectStandardError(true);` merges stdout and stderr; `getErrorStream` returns a null input stream after that.

Comment: @user2357112: Because when I looked it up in the manual I got the opposite answer for what it does.

Comment: That's not what [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) says when I read it: "If the value is set to true, then: [...] the stream returned from Process.getErrorStream() will always be a null input stream"